# jQuery Date Picker Validation Problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, validation, datepicker

I am trying to validate the two input boxes where the user selects a date - i've managed to get far as restricting the user to select a previous date and if they select the first textbox as today's date the next input box must be one day ahead (future date)

On submit i am trying to get it to validate so if you dont select one of the input boxes it gives you an error message.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPickupDate" runat="server" Text="Pick-up Date" CssClass="lblPickup"></asp:Label>
<input type="text" class="datePicker" id="validBeforeDatepicker" value="Please select a date" name="pickupdate" /> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-calendar"></span>

<asp:Label ID="lblReturnDate" runat="server" Text="Return Date" CssClass="lblReturnDate"></asp:Label>
<input type="text" class="datePicker" id="validAfterDatepicker" value="Please select a date" name="returdate" /> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-calendar"></span>

$(function () {
    $("#validBeforeDatepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/assets/img/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: 0,
        required: true,
        message: "This is a required field",
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onClose: function() {$(this).valid();}
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#validAfterDatepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/assets/img/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate: +1,
        required: true,
        message: "This is a required field",
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onClose: function() {$(this).valid();}
    });
});
```

Ive set required to true so shouldn't it throw a validation error if you miss it?

The site where the form is: http://www.rentruck.co.uk

I've also had a look at this but cant seem to replicate it http://keith-wood.name/uiDatepickerValidation.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try these two validation libraries for [validating the jQuery UI Datepicker](http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/validating_the_jquery_ui_datepicker).

[Working Example for H5F](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/jquery/1.7.2/2628275/)

**CSS**:

```
.valid {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
.error {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
​
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="h5ftest">
    <input type="date" required pattern="\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}">
</form>​
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(function() {
  H5F.setup( $( "#h5ftest" ) );

  $( "[type=date]" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
      $( this ).focus().blur();
    }
  });
});​
```

or Working Example for [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/gist/jquery/1.7.2/2628089/)

**CSS**:

```
.valid {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
.error {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}​
​
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="jQueryValidateTest">
    <input type="date" required>
</form>​
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(function() {

  $( "#jQueryValidateTest" ).validate();

  $( "[type=date]" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
      $( this ).valid();
    }
  });
});​
```

Comment: perfect! works for me fine :) i've used all ASP.NET controls instead of having some HTML Controls as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for made my day good through the above solution. Though the solution is nice, am not able to work this in IE. How to make this work in IE ? Is there any possibilities ? @chridam

Comment: @gkrishy Could you please create a new question that has your exact issue?

Comment: @chridam  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161644/datepicker-validation-is-not-working-on-using-jquery-plugin    Check this link. I posted my new question over there. Do some needful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

On the [Datepicker site](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) in `View source` section they are suggest to check date range manually on `onClose` event:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that changes the look of the form - the way i did it was restricting the user from selecting a previous date which is now sorted - I'm trying to get it to when the user clicks the submit button it needs to show error message but i cant use the runat="server" on the datepicker input field as it doesnt work then